# Spring Data Projections with database Stream

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I've searched around for quite a bit but can't seem to find a solution to this problem.

TL;DR: The issue deals with using [Spring Data Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) in conjunction with [Spring Data Streams](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-streaming). Trying to pull an entity's children in a Stream using Projections throws an error

I have a Candidate class (with a OneToMany relationship with CandidateField):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Candidates")
public class Candidate {
  @Column(name = "State")
  private String state;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "CandidateID", referencedColumnName = "CandidateID")
  private Set<CandidateField> fields;
  //Getters & Setters omitted
}
```

And it has the following projection:

```
public interface StateAndTrade{
  String getState();
  Set<CandidateField> getFields();
}
```

If I use the following repository method to pull just the State, it works:

```
@Query("select c.state as state from Candidate c")
Stream<StateAndTrade> streamState();
```

But if I try to pull the children (CandidateFields) with this method:

```
@Query("select c.state as state, c.fields as fields from Candidate c")
Stream<StateAndTrade> streamStateTrade();
```

The following error comes up:

```
2017-05-15 14:43:45.618 DEBUG 1180 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select candidate0_.State as col_0_0_, . as col_1_0_, fields1_.CandidateFieldID as Candidat1_11_, fields1_.CandidateID as Candidat2_11_, fields1_.Current as Current3_11_, fields1_.FieldID as FieldID4_11_, fields1_.Name as Name5_11_ from Candidate.Candidates candidate0_ inner join Candidate.CandidateFields fields1_ on candidate0_.CandidateID=fields1_.CandidateID
Hibernate: select candidate0_.State as col_0_0_, . as col_1_0_, fields1_.CandidateFieldID as Candidat1_11_, fields1_.CandidateID as Candidat2_11_, fields1_.Current as Current3_11_, fields1_.FieldID as FieldID4_11_, fields1_.Name as Name5_11_ from Candidate.Candidates candidate0_ inner join Candidate.CandidateFields fields1_ on candidate0_.CandidateID=fields1_.CandidateID
2017-05-15 14:43:45.641  WARN 1180 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2017-05-15 14:43:45.641 ERROR 1180 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as col_1_0_, fields1_.CandidateFieldID as Candidat1_11_, fields1_.CandidateID as' at line 1
2017-05-15 14:43:45.664 ERROR 1180 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter     : Forwarding to error page from request [/admin/stats/all] due to exception [could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet]

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:241) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.streamStateTrade(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at co.workamerica.contexts.candidates.services.AdminCandidateService.findAllStateAndTrade(AdminCandidateService.java:62) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at co.workamerica.contexts.candidates.services.AdminCandidateService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$11e7b278.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at co.workamerica.contexts.candidates.services.AdminCandidateService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bcd5b9f8.findAllStateAndTrade(<generated>) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at co.workamerica.contexts.gateways.platform.dashboard.services.AdminDashboardStatsService.emailAllCandidateTradeAndStateStats(AdminDashboardStatsService.java:48) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at co.workamerica.contexts.gateways.platform.dashboard.controllers.AdministratorDashboardController.getAllCandidateTradeAndStateStats(AdministratorDashboardController.java:140) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2117) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.scroll(Loader.java:2693) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.scroll(QueryLoader.java:570) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.scroll(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:423) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performScroll(HQLQueryPlan.java:350) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.scroll(SessionImpl.java:1420) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.scroll(QueryImpl.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.provider.PersistenceProvider$HibernateScrollableResultsIterator.<init>(PersistenceProvider.java:428) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.provider.PersistenceProvider$1.executeQueryWithResultStream(PersistenceProvider.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$StreamExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:343) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:85) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 88 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as col_1_0_, fields1_.CandidateFieldID as Candidat1_11_, fields1_.CandidateID as' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2501) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 113 common frames omitted
```

The issue in the generated query seems to be at "select candidate0_.State as col_0_0_, . as col_1_0_" where it's using a period? to select the children

If I try to create a stream without @Query then it loads the data in one go as if I used a List:

```
Stream<StateAndTrade> streamAllByOrderByState();
```

I've been stuck on this issue for a while and would love some insight on to how I can resolve it. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to put instead of `@Query("select c.state as state from Candidate c")`, just `@Query("from Candidate c")`. As far I know, the spring data projection API will handle all the dirty stuff

Comment: Hey, if I do @Query("from Candidate c") then it throws this
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases!`
It's expecting me to map the fields from Candidate to StateAndTrade I would assume

Comment: Try `"select c from Candidate c"` or just `"from Candidate"`

Comment: Hey @JensSchauder, "select c from Candidate c" worked but I'm 100% sure I tried that before, most likely had another issue that made me blame the repository method. Thanks for your help. Would you want to add that as an answer below?
FYI "from Candidate" throws the same `Java.lang.IllegalStateException: No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases!`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
"select c.state as state, c.fields as fields from Candidate c"
```

Is unnecessary complicated and seems to throwof something.

```
"select c from Candidate c"
```

works fine.